# Weirdness with Kotlinx serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor

I'm getting an error serializing an object that depends on how serialization is invoked.

The JSON config:

```
kotlin
    fun configureJson() = Json {
        prettyPrint = true
        isLenient = true
    }
```

Installed:

```
kotlin
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(configureJson())
    }
```

This fails:

```
call.receive<T>()
```

This succeeds:

```
configureJson().decodeFromString<T>(call.receiveText())
```

The exact same JSON configuration that is applied to the Application is used to marshal the object

Comment: What is the exact json and error?

Answer (score 2):

The `ContentNegotiation` plugin negotiates the media type based on the `Content-Type` header.

I suspect here the inbound request does not have the request header `Content-Type: application/json`, therefore `receive<T>()` does not apply the JSON transformation via `ContentNegotiation`.

The manual decoding of the result of `receiveText()` works, because it bypasses the content negotiation -- it reads the body of the request as text, and then explicitly treats that text as JSON and decodes `T` from there.

Try changing the request to include the `Content-Type` header. If you have no control over the request, you can create a custom serializer. Se https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#register_custom and https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#implement_custom_serializer.